# Applescript with Tunnelblick selecting random VPN

Tags: applescript

I've been trying to write a simple applescript to get a list of availible VPN connections and pick a random one, here it is:

```
tell application "Tunnelblick"
    set the_values_list to get configurations
    set the list_count to the count of the_values_list --gets number of items in list
    set pick to random number from 1 to list_count --has it choose a random item
    set generated_choice to item pick of the_values_list --sets the generated item as the choice
    return generated_choice --displays the choice
end tell
```

This returns:

> configuration "USA.Indiana.SouthBend_LOC1S2.UDP" of application "Tunnelblick"

However if I try to connect by replacing the return:

```
connect generated_choice --displays the choice
```

I get an error:

> Tunnelblick got an error: Invalid key form.

Why could this be happening? It seems like it's passing in arrays (list) pocked instead of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked

`connect (get name of (configuration pick))`